# Reading file line by line, character by character

Tags: c, file, io

I have a file with two numbers of unknown lenght per line, separated by a white space. The numbers can be of any size have up to 500 digits, so i need to read it character by character and store it into an array of integers. I tried something like this:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) { // assuming buff handles the line lenght
//read each character until ''
   // store it
//read each character until '\n'
  // store it
}
```

I tried using fgetc to read until ' ' and '\n' but it didnt work. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Your code looks kind of suspect: first, you have a syntax error and a logical one: it should be something like `while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp) != NULL){ … }`. Second, it's hard to get into what kind of array do you have to store what you've read? An integer array? A float array? A character array? Do you "need to perform different actions" on the numbers or on their decimal representations of digits as strings of numeric characters? A little more effort from you would help all, including you.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. The stuff i will be doing with the array is not too relevant at this moment. I just wanted to point out that a line by line read would be necessary  since i will do different operations with the numbers for each line.

Comment: Why not just read numbers as `double`s? They can be "of any size"...

Comment: They can have any number of digits. For example : 300! That's why im trying to read it character by character.

Answer (score 1):

You should not read one character at a time.  Instead, read one line at a time:

```
int num1, num2;

while (fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n", &num1, &num2) == 2) {
    // do something with num1 and num2
}
```

---

Edit: OK, now you say the numbers can be super gigantic.  No problem, just use `libgmp`!  https://gmplib.org/manual/I_002fO-of-Integers.html

For example:

```
mpz_t num1, num2;
mpz_init(num1);
mpz_init(num2);

while (mpz_inp_str(num1, fp, 10) && mpz_inp_str(num2, fp, 10)) {
    // do something with num1 and num2
}
```

GMP gives you unlimited precision, so you can store numbers of any length, and do math on them.

Comment: The numbers can be of any size, so i cant read it like an int.

Comment: @TrapezeraBuscando: OK, I updated my answer now to allow reading integers of any length.

Answer (score 1):

If you take `long double` format, I believe you can deal with almost any reasonable "size", beside that you don't have to worry about "handling line length".

```
 long double num1, num2;

 while (fscanf(fp, "%Lf %Lf\n", &num1, &num2) == 2){
    printf("%Lf\t%Lf\n", num1, num2);
 //copy the numbers into whichever appropriate array
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunatly the numbers wont have a reasonable size. I really can't use any data type to store it. Isn't there a way to read it ,character by character, until the white space and store every character into the first array, and doing that again for a second array until the end of the line?

Comment: In your place, assuming that you deal with a regular file, I would have gotten rid of the _file reading_ in as few steps as possible. (1) Declare a character array big enough, `buf[512][512]`, upper limit isn't guaranteed because of of stack size considerations. (2) Read the file into this array using `int i = 0; while(fscanf(fp, "%s", buf[i++]) == 1); fclose(fp)` . Then you can do whatever you like with this char array. A single digit fits the `char` format, no need for any array of `int`s.