# Reading file character by character, line by line in C

Tags: c, file, io

I have a file with multiple lines. Each line has two numbers separated by a white-space. *I need to use this code,* which prints the first line, to print the whole file, **but doing it *line by line***

```
do
{
   fscanf(fp,"%c", &c);
   if(c == ' ')
     break;
   printf("%c", c);
}
while (c != ' ');

do
{
   fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);
   printf("%c", c);
}
while( c != '\n');
```

I tried to use fgets but got into an infinite loop.

```
while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) != NULL) // assuming buf can handle the line lenght
{
   //code above
}
```

Why i cant use fgets like that to print it line by line?

Sample

Input:

`10  5003
 20  320
 4003 200`

Output

```
10 5003
20 320
4003 200
```

Comment: Please see this [recently asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089493/reading-file-line-by-line-character-by-character) which also stipulates *The numbers can be of any size have up to 500 digits*.

Comment: That question was asked by me .None of the answers solve's  this specific problem .

Comment: If the 500 digit possibility is still there, please add it to the question before anyone suggests using `int` or `fscanf(fp, "%d%d", &m, &n);`

Comment: The question emphasises that the first code needs to be used. Isn't that enough?

Comment: So you don't need to store anything? Just output digits? Please provide sample input file and desired output.

Comment: I will do things other than printing, but the main issue is how to read the file line by line using the the first code.

Comment: Post definition of `line`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously I can't use your exact code, or you would not have asked the question, but this is a similar idea, done a bit differently, and also using the `fgets` which was causing you trouble. It works by searching each line for digits, and non-digits. Note that I have `#define MAXLEN 2000` to be generous, because in the previous question, you say each number can have 500 digits, so the line might be at least 1000 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXLEN  2000

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[MAXLEN];
    char *ptr;
    if((fp = fopen("test.txt", "rt")) == NULL)
        return 0;                               // or other action

    while(fgets(line, MAXLEN, fp) != NULL) {
        ptr = line;
        // first number
        while(*ptr && !isdigit(*ptr)) {        // skip non-digits
            ptr++;
        }
        while(*ptr && isdigit(*ptr)) {
            printf("%c", *ptr++);              // print digits
        }
        printf(" ");

        // second number
        while(*ptr && !isdigit(*ptr)) {        // skip non-digits
            ptr++;
        }
        while(*ptr && isdigit(*ptr)) {
            printf("%c", *ptr++);              // print digits
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT** you could make it more concise like this, with a loop to read each set of digits:

```
char *terminate = " \n";                    // 1st number ends with space, 2nd with newline
int i;
while(fgets(line, MAXLEN, fp) != NULL) {
    ptr = line;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
        while(*ptr && !isdigit(*ptr)) {     // skip non-digits
            ptr++;
        }
        while(*ptr && isdigit(*ptr)) {
            printf("%c", *ptr++);           // print digits
        }
        printf("%c", terminate[i]);         // space or newline
    }
}
```

Program output (from your input):

```
10 5003
20 320
4003 200
```

Answer (score 1):

If we replace printf(fp, "%c", c) with printf("%c", c) (because we are not printing in a file, right?), the following sample should do the job (it creates test file with ten lines).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "w+");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "Test line %i\n", i);
    }

    rewind(fp);

    do {
        do {
            fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);
            if (c == ' ')
                break;
            printf("%c", c);
        } while (c != ' ');
        do {
            fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);
            printf("%c", c);
        } while (c != '\n');
    }while ((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF?printf("%c", c):0);

    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Isn't the last while comparing pointer and integer? (fgetc(fp)!=NULL)

Comment: Thanks for finding this mistake, last line should read "while (fgetc(fp)!=EOF)" instead of "while (fgetc(fp)!=NULL && !feof(fp))" (I've just edited the post)

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake in my reply, the condition of the do-while loop should read "while ((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF?printf("%c", c):0);", i.e. we read a char in c, and if it's not EOF - we print it, otherwise we end the loop by returning 0 as a result of the ?: operator.