# Dynamic buffer fgets in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, fgets

I've been searching on how to allocate a dynamic buffer using `fgets`, but I can't seem to get it on this example. The file has two numbers of unknown length separated by a white-space. For every line it reads  each character until `' '` and `\n` and prints it.

```
char *ptr;
char line[MAX];

while(fgets(line, sizeof line , fp) != NULL){
     ptr = line;
     for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        while(*ptr && (*ptr) != ' '){     
             if(*ptr == ' ')
                break;   
             k = (*ptr) - '0';
             if(k != -38)    // wont print '\n'
                printf("%d", k);            
             ptr++;
        }
       while(*ptr && (*ptr) != '\n') {
             if(*ptr == ' '){
                ptr++;
                continue;
             }      
             k = (*ptr) - '0';
             printf("%d", k);       
             ptr++;
     }
   }
}
```

> Can someone give me an idea on how to make  `line` dynamic while still using `ptr` that way?

Comment: What do you mean by _dynamic_? The size? Well, that's not possible. Unless you read the actual data, how are you going to know how much memory you need?

Comment: All the ways I can think of are rather inefficient.

Comment: You say "dynamic" which usually means trying to dynamically allocate an arbitrarily-large buffer for an arbitrarily-large line, but it doesn't look like that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: It looks like `sscanf(line, "%d %d", &k1, &k2)` would do what you want?

Comment: That funny-looking test `if(k != -38)` suggests you've gone down the wrong path.

Comment: It looks like you're extracting and printing the characters one digit at a time, which is rather odd, and likely not what you'll want when you get this working.  For example, if you read the line `"123 456"` you probably want to extract the numbers 123 and 456.  But it looks like what your code is doing now is extracting and printing 1, 2, 3, space, 4, 5, 6?

Comment: I ment a buffer that could be reallocated at run time, depending on the line lenght. I can not store the numbers in any data type since they can have any lenght (bigger then long long).

Comment: It actually skips the space and \n. I understand that this example is far from beeing optimal for simply printing the numbers, but i will need to use it for other purposes later.

Comment: In a similar [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091965/reading-file-character-by-character-line-by-line-in-c/37092563) the numbers might not fit any standard type of integer variable (up to 500 digits). Is this the case here?

Comment: @WeatherVane Indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
size_t linelen = 80;
char *line = malloc(linelen);

while(magic_reallocating_fgets(&line, &linelen, fp) != NULL) {
    /* ... do whatever you want with line ... */
}
```

But then, of course, the $64,000 question is, what does `magic_reallocating_fgets` look like?  It's something like this:

```
char *magic_reallocating_fgets(char **bufp, size_t *sizep, FILE *fp) {
    size_t len;
    if(fgets(*bufp, *sizep, fp) == NULL) return NULL;
    len = strlen(*bufp);
    while(strchr(*bufp, '\n') == NULL) {
        *sizep += 100;
        *bufp = realloc(*bufp, *sizep);
        if(fgets(*bufp + len, *sizep - len, fp) == NULL) return *bufp;
        len += strlen(*bufp + len);
    }
    return *bufp;
}
```

That's not really complete code, it's almost pseudocode.  I've left two things for you as exercises:

It has no error-checking on the `malloc` and `realloc` calls.

It's kinda grossly inefficient, in that it makes not one but two extra passes over each line it reads: to count the characters, and again to look for a `'\n'`.  (It turns out `fgets`'s interface isn't ideal for this kind of work.)

Comment: This is why `fgetc` is a simpler, more elegant, and probably faster solution.

Comment: @CareyGregory But if you care about efficiency, use `getc`, not `fgetc`!

Comment: I see. Im using fgets because i'll need to make various operations with the numbers depending on the line, and it's easy to keep track of the line im in with that function.

Comment: @CareyGregory In any case, I'm not sure I can agree with you. I have discovered that hand-rolled line-reading loops using `getc` can be significant bottlenecks, running substantially slower than the library `fgets`.  But I've never been able to figure out why.  (With that said, I've also never actually written or used something quite like the `magic_reallocating_fgets` I presented here.  Here, I was toeing the "use standard library functions if possible" party line.  Perhaps I'll investigate the performance of this kind of code more some day.)

Comment: @SteveSummit The getc/fgetc functions will never be as fast as `fgets` for the simple reason that there are more function calls involved to read a single line of text. But logic that can read an arbitrarily long line of text with getc/fgetc would be **much** simpler, cleaner, and more maintainable than anything involving `fgets`. I've actually seen a compiler that used `fgetc` to read source files. When you're parsing source, char-by-char is how you usually want your input, and done properly it can be acceptably fast.

Comment: @CareyGregory I know what you're saying, but note that `getc` is *not* necessarily a function!

Comment: @CareyGregory I suspect one reason the library `fgets` can be faster is that it can peek directly into the `stdin` buffer, scanning quickly for the `\n`.

Comment: glibc's fgets is magic in exactly the way you envision (see my answer). However as far as I can tell, none of the Microsoft CRT's (many) versions of fgets are magic. I'm not sure, there are a lot of them and the documentation isn't very good. Perhaps I missed some "magic" somewhere :-)

Comment: I've discovered that another big issue is thread locking, in a Posix environment.  A `getc` loop will be unacceptably slow, unless bracketed with `flockfile`/`funlockfile`.

Answer (score 3):

On systems with glibc >= 2.7, or POSIX.1-2008 support, what I think you want can be accomplished using:

```
char *line;
while (fscanf(f, "%m[^\n]\n", &line) == 1) {
    /* do stuff with line */
    free(line);
}
```

This works great on my Linux systems, but over in the Windows universe, Microsoft Visual C++ supports neither %m, nor any equivalent that I can find.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size of an array during run time in C. It is illegal. This is because arrays are allocated from the stack. To have the size be dynamic you would have to declare a pointer, and allocate the memory for it dynamically. This data is allocated from the heap.

You can change the size of allocated memory by using `realloc`.

```
int lineLen = 80;
char *line;
line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 80);
if (line == NULL) {
    // Something went horribly wrong
    exit(1);
}
while (fgets(line, lineLen, fp)) {
    // Do something to find the size
    line = (char *)realloc(line, sizeof(char) * newLen);
    if (line == NULL) {
        // Something went horribly wrong
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

However, allocating and reallocating memory is a rather expensive operation. As a result, you may be more effective by just choosing a big buffer size, if you can do that safely. If you have a short loop then it may not be significant enough to worry about, but it is probably not advisable to be constantly changing your buffer's size.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc`. Its return type is `void *` which can be implicitly converted to any pointer type, so there's no point in casting it.

Comment: @squirl he might be using a C++ compiler, which requires casting malloc